# How to insert multiple Django blocks into one template?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, block

I am trying to use more different views in one template via different blocks or include method but I have got stuck. My aim is to implement my different views into one template. I tried to more solution but these haven't worked for me. I show these solution:

**My views:**

```
def  dashboard_data(request):
    # Here I collect data from my PostgreSQL database I push these into 
    #Objects and I send it to my test_a.html via render like below.

    return render(request, 'my_project/test_a.html', send_data)

def chart_data(request):
    #In these view my final goal is to collect data from database and create 
    #charts but for the simplicity I just use a list (a=[1,2,3,4]) and I 
    #push it to the test_b.html and I render it.


    render(request, 'my_project/test_b.html', send_data))
```

**My templates:**

1, base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  {% block title %}<title>My project</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Include CSS files -->
  {% load static %}
  <!-- Include CSS files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-table.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

     {% block sidebar %}

     {% endblock %}

     {% block content%}
     {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

1, test_a.html

```
  {% extends "monitor/base.html" %}

  {%block content%}

  {%for i in table%}
       <p> {{i.record}}</p>
  {%endfor%} 

  {%endblock}
```

2, test b.html

```
  {%for i in a%}
       <p> {{i}}</p>
  {%endfor}
```

So my goal would be that the test_b.html's result could appear in the base.html.

**My solutions:**

**A**: I tried to put into a block the test_b.html and integrate in the base.html

*1, base.html (test1):*

```
 {% block conent%}

 {% endblock %}

 {% block chart%}

 {% endblock %}
```

*1, test_b.html (test1)*:

```
{% extends "monitor/base.html" %}

{%block chart%}    

{%for i in a%}
       <p> {{i}}</p>
{%endfor}

{%endblock%}
```

**B**: I tried to use  `{{ block.super }}`

*1, base.html (test1):*

```
 {% block conent%}

 {% endblock %}
```

*1, test_b.html (test1)*:

```
{% extends "monitor/base.html" %}

{%block content%}    
 {{ block.super }} 
{%for i in a%}
       <p> {{i}}</p>
{%endfor}

{%endblock%}
```

**C:** Finally I used include method too but I didn't work for me as well. Here I tried to use simple html tags like (`<p>Hello world</p>`) int the test_b.html and worked. So If I do not use variables it works but I have to use my variables from my views.

*1, test_a.html*

```
{% extends "monitor/base.html" %}

{%block chart%}    

{%for i in a%}
      <p> {{i}}</p>
{%endfor}

{%endblock%}
{% include "my_project/test_b.html" %}
```

*2, test_b.html*

```
{%for i in a%}
     <p> {{i}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can't render two views at the same time, a view is just a callable that returns a response, however you can, in a view, call different functions!  Another road is to use a context_processor, but you have to use it only if you need data to be accessible in all view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alessioferri20 mentioned, you cannot render 2 views at the same time. Basically, one view corresponds to one HTTP request & response.

You can achieve what you want by using custom template tags:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

---

> but I have to use my variables from my views.

For example, `chart_data` could be an inclusion tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), here is some pseudo-code:

Let's say you want to show a chart for the `age_stats` from your view:

```
def your_view(request, ...):
    age_stats = {...}
    ....
    return render(request, "template...", {'age_stats': age_stats})
```

In your template:

```
{% chart age_stats %}
```

In your template tags:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('path-to/chart.html')
def chart(input_data):
    # collect data from database & use the input_data coming from your view
    data = ...
    return {'data': data}
```

Answer (score 3):

To include an HTML file from another file just use `{% include 'htmlfilename.hml' %}` 
outside `{% block your_block_name %}{% endblock %}` if it's a base template.

You can learn more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

```
<body>
     {% include 'header.html' %}
     {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
     {% block content%}{% endblock %}
     {% include 'footer.html' %}
</body>
```

If you want to use some functionality across several templates then use  [inclusion_tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Answer (score 0):

The `{% include %}` tag is how you insert other templates into blocks. These templates don't need to be registered in views.py or urls.py.

For example:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block home %} {% load static %}
<div>
<h1>Some Title</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div>
{% include 'some-other-template.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/