# How do I insert multiple blocks into the base.html in Django?

Tags: python, django

Possibly I'm misunderstanding the inheritance of templates in Django, but why doesn't the below code work? Both child templates are inheriting from the parent template with different block names.

**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>test</h1>

{% block index %}{% endblock %}
{% block nav %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block index %}
<h1>This is the index.html page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**nav.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block nav %}
<h1>This is the nav.html</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I am accessing this template by:
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

**blog/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('nav/', views.home, name='nav')
]
```

**blog/views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html')
```

Using the URL of:

```
localhost:8000/blog
```

**HTML Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>test</h1>


<h1>This is the index.html page</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to grasp the concept of using multiple blocks so that I can place them on the templates that I need.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? How are you accessing this template and what isn't working exactly? Are you sure the path to 'blog/base.html' is correct?

Comment: I've edited to show how I'm accessing it

Comment: use `include` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497062/how-to-insert-multiple-django-blocks-into-one-template

Comment: I'm sorry, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django templates: include and extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408925/django-templates-include-and-extends)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not render two views in one HTTP request. To include content from a different template, simply use `include` for the `nav.html` if its is not going to be called independently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>test</h1>
{% include 'nav.html' %}
{% block index %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```